Can't use multiple authentication ways
Sorry if there’s already such a topic, couldn’t find it.
Could you please tell if there is a way to use different authentication ways at the same time?
For example if I add a fingerprint (with fprintd 1.9.42 and pam-auth-update) I can only select to use:

only password
only fingerprint
password and then fingerprint

But I want to use fingerprint OR password (what I prefer at the moment),
or at least fingerprint and if it doesn’t work, then password.
And similar situation with camera auth (faceID). I installed howdy 2.6.1, added my face and it even works when I want to use sudo it recognizes me, but when I try to login to my OS user it doesn’t recognize me and the worth thing is that it dowsn’t even ask password, just block me.
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Kernel: 6.5.0-28-generic #29~22.04.1-Ubuntu
plasmashell: 5.24.7
Qt: 5.15.3
KDE Frameworks: 5.92.0
kf5-config: 1.0

Laptop:
Lenovo ThinkPad T14s Gen 4 AMD (21F9S0T900)

Thanks in advance!

As a workaround, you may want to press Escape then press Enter on your keyboard, when the fingerprint fails. That will cancel the waiting of password input attempt.
I am not sure if this solves your question, but this is what I do normally.
